# I want to use gestureRecognizer for push vc but it is not working

Tags: swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var singleView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    singleView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    let vc = CategoryViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I click on view but it does not push to vc.
but it works when I print in the method. So there is no problem in the method.

Comment: Because `navigationController` is nil.

Comment: How can ı fix it

Comment: It's not going to have a navigation controller by magic. You cannot push unless this view controller is already in a navigation interface. Evidently, it isn't. You have not told us how this navigation controller comes to exist, where you configure it, etc., so how are we supposed to help you? We are programmers, not telepaths.

Comment: It's 2023 - there's no need to still be using #selectors! Instead, find the `Tap Gesture Recognizer` in the Interface Builder library, and then drag and drop it onto the `singleView` view in Main.storyboard. Then, set up an `@IBAction` named `handleTap` by ctrl-click and dragging from the Tap Gesture Recognizer (in the left sidebar) to your ViewController.swift file. This `@IBAction` function already recognizes the tap gesture as its sender, thus doing away with the selector. Delete your `@objc` function, and copy and paste everything inside it to your new `@IBAction` function.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner, I'm lacking in asking questions, but I already found the answer. Thanks for your help anyway, I hope we will improve in helping each other in the future.

Comment: @HBK This won't fix the problem of the Navigation Controller being nil, but it will streamline your code and avoid having to specify the sender

Comment: I fixed the problem ı added navigationController embed in and solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a navigation controller (Embed in) to the Viev controller. I also added Tap Gesture Recognizer instead of @objc func to make my code cleaner. Final and working state of the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var singleView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    let vc = CategoryViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Nice! Because it's an @IBAction, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is implicitly unwrapped, so you don't need the `? = nil` part. You can use just `(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)`